# How to set longitude to negative in Applescript, in iPhoto?

Tags: applescript, iphoto

I have thousands of photos in iPhoto (due to an import from a bad data source) with bad geodata, where all the longitudes lost their minus signs.

In *every* case, I just want to put a minus sign on the longitude.

How can I, for every photo, set longitude = -longitude?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but +1 anyway for your story about Apple moving the prime meridian to the Pacific ocean:)

Comment: Not Apple's fault; I think it was the Flickr export script I used's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script set the longitude to negative.

```
tell application "iPhoto"
    set tc to count photos
    repeat with i from 1 to tc
        try
            tell photo i to if longitude > 0 then set longitude to -(longitude)
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Perfect. I actually used 45 instead of 0, because I remembered that I had a couple of trips to Europe in there.